Tobit Model Normality Assumption
For the tobit model, I am a bit confused by the assumption of normality. Is it that my dependent variable must be normally distributed? Or is it that my model's latent residuals must be normally distributed?
Thank you

The normality assumption is indeed on the residuals of your latent model, which looks like
$y^* = X\beta + u$, where $u$ is normally distributed and $y^*$ represents your latent (unobserved) variable.
